# Python Reading data from two input files

Tags: python

I need to create a python file which reads data from two separate input files and feeds it into a different main program file. Can someone please help me with the code for reading the data from the input files? The input file data is formatted as shown below:

**grades.txt :**

```
87965202,3127C4

87965221,2496B3

87965208,6703D3

87965221,2674C4
```

**students.txt :**

```
87965164,Paris,Yu,6/27/1997

87965219,Heath,Moss,10/13/1996

87965187,Cale,Blankenship,10/22/1995

87965220,Terrence,Watkins,12/7/1996
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Can you please make your question precise? What is the output file's format? What have you tried so far? Seems you are just copy-pasting your assignment question. All one could figure out is grades.txt and students.txt represent two tables with the first field (seems regno or something) as the primary/foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to read the lines from each file into a list you can use this

```
gradesFile = open("grades.txt")
studentsFile = open("students.txt")

grades = gradesFile.readlines()
students = studentsFile.readlines()

gradesFile.close()
studentsFile.close()

print(grades)
print(students)
```

If you're working with the data you're gonna have to [rstrip](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm) the newlines and you will need to use the full path if the files you want to read is in a different directory than your python program